# Identity Server 3 with multiple URL for a same Client

Tags: c#, authentication, single-sign-on, identityserver3

I designed an Identity Server for a Single Sign on. I hosed my client application in different domains. Kindly have a look at this Client

```
new Client
{
    Enabled = true,
    ClientName = "Super UI",
    ClientId = "Super",
    Flow = Flows.Implicit,
    RequireConsent = false,
    RequireSignOutPrompt =false,
    RedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "http://localhost:3001/callback",
        "http://localhost:3002/callback",
        "http://localhost:3003/callback"
    },

    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>
    {
        "http://localhost:3001/",
        "http://localhost:3002/",
        "http://localhost:3003/"
    },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "http://localhost:3001/logout",
        "http://localhost:3002/logout",
        "http://localhost:3003/logout"
    },
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        "openid",
        "profile",
        "email",
        "SuperUI"
    }
}
```

But Its failing, I can't able to login using this settings

If I use a single URL, then its working

```
new Client
{
    Enabled = true,
    ClientName = "Super UI",
    ClientId = "Super",
    Flow = Flows.Implicit,
    RequireConsent = false,
    RequireSignOutPrompt =false,
    RedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "http://localhost:3001/callback"
    },

    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>
    {
        "http://localhost:3001/"
    },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "http://localhost:3001/logout"
    },
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        "openid",
        "profile",
        "email",
        "SuperUI"
    }
}
```

I searched lot of blogs and search engines, there is no clear idea about this and there is one question in Github https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/3340

Kindly assist me in this regards.

Answer (score 1):

Well this should work. I've set up multiple clients like this. Did you implement your own `IRedirectUriValidator`? That might contain a bug. Debugging the app and looking at the debug output always helps me identify issues (see [identityserver logging documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/logging.html)).

P.s. don't implement your own `IRedirectUriValidator` because your configuration should work without your own implementation.

Comment: I'm having one more issue in Identity Server Logout... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766353/automatically-signout-all-active-clients-in-identity-server-once-logout-of-any-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758783/logout-all-client-in-an-identity-server-3