# Automatically Signout all active clients in Identity server once logout of any client

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, single-sign-on, logout, identityserver3

I'm using Identity Server 3 for Single Sign on and I'm having 3 client application. Once I logged in any of the Client application, the rest of the two applications, won't ask the Authenticate credentials.

Its working fine in Log-in but in Signout the current Client gets logged out but the rest of the two applications not automatically redirecting to the log-in page of Identity Server.

Kindly assist me in this regards.

Comment: Single sign-out support is already explained into the official documentation: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/signout.html

Comment: @FedericoDipuma - I tried already. Let me know it will automatically logged out all the logged in application ? (i.e., automatic redirect)

Comment: What type of clients do you have? Are they JavaScript clients? Mvc? I'm asking because this is a feature that needs to be enabled on the clients itself; they need to check whether the user is still logged in because the clients received tokens which are still valid

Comment: @Zenuka - I'm using javascript client. I downloaded a copy of Identity Server and modified the client information (In-Memory), its working fine, then I created a new Identity Server application, in that I moved all the In-memory information to Database. Its working fine except the logout.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said in the comments that your client is a JavaScript client, you can use the [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) lib from the guys behind IdentityServer. It has an event [`userSignedOut`](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki#user-content-events) which should fire when the user is signed out from a different client.

Comment: Yes, I'm using oidc-client.js - actual downloaded version (In-memory) works as expected but the database version is not working (i.e., I moved the Scopes, Claims, Clients to DB), Its not functioning as expected only in logout section rest of the functionalities are working fine. My problem is if I logout in one client, rest the clients needs to logout automatically.

Comment: Then it might be good to check your in memory configuration vs db configuration, there must be some difference.

Comment: Let me know any specific module is there related to this logout?